# Adding New Query to Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio

I am trying to follow [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L1m1Znj9dZA&index=2&list=PL3Q5eEb3qAohlydySyM-2ytTCyTRLoIso) and get stuck at 2:43 where he right clicks the database in server explorer and clicks 'New Query', once I do that it brings up the right sql file tab, but in the dropdown box where it has all the available databases, the one I created is not there, it only contains 'master, model, msdb, tempdb' I've tried searching for an answer and cannot find one.

Comment: Are you sur you have create your base? Have you try to close VS and reopen?

Comment: Yes, I just closed and open and it's still there, I'm running VS 2015 and SQL Express 2014